# Use latest sheet in formula vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am using an excel sheet that should reference to the latest sheet in a series
Inlife (n), I got the VBA so that it replaces the reference if I manually tell it which sheet to use. I cannot simply use the last sheet or the 5th of all sheets or something.
However the position is always the sheet before sheet RG. I tried to use the same code as for copy and paste: =before... but this didn't get me anywhere, neither did count like below.

```
   Dim result As Integer 
   result = Count(If ws.Name = "Inlife" Or ws.Name Like "Inlife (*)")

ActiveSheet.Select

        Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:B25")
    

    For Each cel In rng
    cel.Formula = Replace(cel.Formula, "Inlife", "'Inlife (result)'")

    Next
```

This doesn't work at all but I hope you understand my intention.
(I am sure this looks ridiculous but I do not know how else to describe my problem)

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update Formula Worksheet References

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateFormulaWorksheetReferences()
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    Const ProcName As String = "UpdateFormulaWorksheetReferences"
    
    Const dfCellAddress As String = "B3"
    Const ashName As String = "RG"
    Const swsBaseName As String = "Inlife"
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination worksheet.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ActiveSheet
    
    ' Check if there is any data in the destination column.
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dfCellAddress)
    Dim dlCell As Range
    Set dlCell = dfCell.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - dfCell.Row + 1) _
        .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If dlCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No data in cell '" & dfCellAddress & "' or below.", _
            vbCritical, ProcName
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Create a reference to the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = dws.Parent
    
    ' Attempt to create a reference to the After sheet.
    Dim ash As Object
    On Error Resume Next
        Set ash = wb.Sheets(ashName)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    If ash Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no sheet named '" & ashName & "'.", _
            vbCritical, ProcName
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Attempt to create a reference to the Source worksheet, the worksheet
    ' before the After sheet.
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        Set sws = wb.Sheets(ashName).Previous
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    If sws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no worksheet before sheet '" & ashName & "'.", _
            vbCritical, ProcName
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Check if the Source worksheet's name begins with the Base name.
    Dim swsName As String: swsName = sws.Name
    If InStr(1, swsName, swsBaseName, vbTextCompare) <> 1 Then
        MsgBox "The worksheet name doesn't start with '" & swsBaseName & "'.", _
            vbCritical, ProcName
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Check if there is a formula containing the Base name
    ' in the first Destination cell.
    Dim dFormula As Variant
    Dim dPos As String
    dFormula = CStr(dfCell.Formula)
    dPos = InStr(1, dFormula, swsBaseName, vbTextCompare)
    If dPos = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The Base name '" & swsBaseName & "' was not found in cell '" _
            & dfCellAddress & "'.", vbCritical, ProcName
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Check if the formula is referencing ('!') the Base name.
    dFormula = Right(dFormula, Len(dFormula) - dPos + 1)
    dPos = InStr(dFormula, "!")
    If dPos = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The cell '" & dfCellAddress _
            & "' doesn't contain a worksheet reference.", vbCritical, ProcName
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Determine the New name (closing parentheses: ')').
    dFormula = Left(dFormula, dPos - 1)
    dPos = InStr(dFormula, ")")
    Dim NewName As String
    If dPos = 0 Then
        NewName = swsBaseName
    Else
        NewName = Left(dFormula, dPos)
    End If
    
    ' Check if the New name is different than the Source worksheet name.
    If StrComp(NewName, swsName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The formulas already contain " _
            & "the correct worksheet references.", vbExclamation, ProcName
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Account for the single quote issues (').
    If StrComp(swsName, swsBaseName, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        swsName = "'" & swsName & "'"
    End If
    If NewName <> swsBaseName Then
        NewName = "'" & NewName & "'"
    End If

    ' Replace the worksheet references in the Destination column range.
    
    Dim dcrg As Range: Set dcrg = dws.Range(dfCell, dlCell)
    
    ' This should work in many cases...
    dFormula = Replace(dfCell.Formula, NewName, swsName, , , vbTextCompare)
    dcrg.Formula = dFormula '  mimics write first cell and copy down
    
'    ' ... if it doesn't, use the fast array loop version...
'    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dcrg.Rows.Count
'    Dim dData As Variant
'    If drCount = 1 Then
'        ReDim dData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): dData(1, 1) = dcrg.Value
'    Else
'        dData = dcrg.Formula
'    End If
'    Dim r As Long
'    For r = 1 To drCount
'        dData(r, 1) = Replace(dData(r, 1), NewName, swsName, , , vbTextCompare)
'    Next r
'    dcrg.Formula = dData
    
'    ' ... or use the slow range loop version:
'    Dim dCell As Range
'    For Each dCell In dcrg.Cells
'        dFormula = Replace(dCell.Formula, NewName, swsName, , , vbTextCompare)
'        dCell.Formula = dFormula
'    Next dCell
  
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "The worksheet reference was changed from '" & NewName & "' to '" _
        & swsName & "'.", vbInformation, ProcName

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Rte '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
        & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

EDIT:

To make it work for multiple columns, instead of `Dim dcrg... dFormula` you could use:

```
Dim drg As Range
Set drg = dws.Range(dfCell, dlCell).EntireRow.Columns("B:O")

Dim dcrg As Range

For Each dcrg In drg.Columns
    dFormula = Replace( _
        dcrg.Cells(1).Formula, NewName, swsName, , , vbTextCompare)
    dcrg.Formula = dFormula
Next dcrg
```

Comment: Hi, This copy down works much much faster, but I can only get it to work for the first column. 
I cannot figure out how to get the last part of your code to work for the full range "B3:O", Could you please enlighten me? This is the basis that I use now: 
`Sheets("Inlife").Copy before:=Sheets("TS")
Sheets("PP").Copy before:=Sheets("RG")
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:O500")
Dim sws As Worksheet
Set sws = Worksheets("TS").Previous` Then I use all the parts of your code without msgboxes or checking cause the `.Previous` seems to work alright as indicator.

Comment: I've added a solution to the bottom of my post. If it doesn't work, you can always take your code and ask another question where you'll explain how it works only for one column but you need it for multiple.

Comment: Marvelous. It worked before but took forever, this works instantly ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the worksheets in order, assigning the latest worksheet to a variable if its name begins with "Inlife". When the loop completes, the variable will be set to the last sheet whose name begins with "Inlife".

```
Sub getinlife()

    Dim last_inlife_sheet As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Check if worksheet name begins with "Inlife"
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, "Inlife") = 1 Then
            Set last_inlife_sheet = ws
        End If
    Next ws
    
    (your code)
    
End Sub
```

I tested this using a workbook I mocked up with the following sheet names:

[image]

and verified that after running the loop, `last_inlife_sheet` was set to the sheet named `Inlife (3)`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me

So I tried to get it to work but when I run this excel tries to open a folder for every reference for which the sheet is replaced ( and running the replacement alone already took way too long).  `cel.Formula = Replace(cel.Formula, "Inlife", ws)` I am obviously not so competent with vba but I tried every variation I could think of and it didn't work, either it would open a document for every formula (and give me a reference error) or it simply said the reference was wrong

Answer (score 1):

Please try the next way:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("RG").Previous
For Each cel In rng
  cel.Formula = Replace(cel.Formula, "Inlife", "'" & ws.name & "'")
Next
```